# angular 5 Application with firebase chat

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am new to angular, I am using angular 5 version, I need to implement firebase in my application for chat purpose, please help to achieve this.

Comment: [Here is the firebase documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), [here is the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/), here is the tutorial on [ask] a question, and here is the explanation for the [mcve] that you need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web) is an official and complete sample which you can use as a starting point